# Javascript browser Bookmarklet

Tags: javascript, bookmarklet

I have the following javascript bookmarklet which opens a new popup window with a facebook post page in side of it.

```
javascript:var d=document,f='http://www.facebook.com/share',l=d.location,e=encodeURIComponent,p='.php?src=bm&v=4&i=1261526047&u='+e(l.href)+'&t='+e(d.title);1;try{if (!/^(.*\.)?facebook\.[^.]*$/.test(l.host))throw(0);share_internal_bookmarklet(p)}catch(z) {a=function() {if (!window.open(f+'r'+p,'sharer','toolbar=0,status=0,resizable=1,width=626,height=436'))l.href=f+p};if (/Firefox/.test(navigator.userAgent))setTimeout(a,0);else{a()}}void(0)
```

I just add that code into the URL of a shortcut link in my browser and it opens the facebook post page and passes the URL and some info about the page I am on to it.

I need to do a much simpler task.  I need to get the URL of the page I am on and either open a new tab or even just use the tab I am in and then open a link like this

```
http://mydomain.com/labs/iframe_header.php?url= PUT THE CURRENT PAGES URL RIGHT HERE
```

As you can see I just need to make a bookmarklet that will take the page I am on and pass it into my sites page.  Can anyone help me, I don't know much javascript at all, would greatly appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
javascript: location.href = 'http://mydomain.com/labs/iframe_header.php?url=' + escape(location.href);
```

This will open in a new window, which will use a new tab if your browser is set up that way:

```
javascript: window.open('http://mydomain.com/labs/iframe_header.php?url=' + escape(location.href));
```

Comment: That is perfect!  Do you know how I could possibly make it open in a new tab when I click it from a link?

Comment: See edit.  You can't control tabs with javascript alone (yet).  But if you use window.open, and you have your browser set to open new windows in a tab, this will do what you want.